# Named temporary file is not being deleted

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, temporary-files

I am creating a named temporary file in a lambda function and I think there could be an issue with the code I have written.

I create a named file, use to create an excel file and then I pass the named file reference to another function to upload to a bucket and it seems like further invocations of the function end up with the disk being full.

I am not entirely sure why calling `close()` does not delete the file from wherever it is on disk.

Here is my function which creates the excel file:

```
def get_excel_file(df_report): 
    tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".xlsx")
    

    with pd.ExcelWriter(tmp_file.name) as writer:       
        df_report.to_excel(
            writer, sheet_name="Report", index=False, startrow=4
        )
        writer.save()

    return tmp_file
```

The returned file `tmp_file` is then passed into the following function to be uploaded, it the parameter named `report`:

```
def upload_renewal_report(bucket_name, report, file_name):    
    s3_client.upload_file(report.name, bucket_name, file_name)

    report.close()
```

Is there anything obviously wrong about the code which would mean the files do not get cleared up?

Report, the object I close on prints out as:

```
WHAT IS REPORT: <tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x7f9aeb9d42e0>

WHAT TYPE IS REPORT: <class 'tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper'>
```

There was a comment which has been removed now which seemed to imply that I was not calling close on the temp file. I do call `close()` on what appears to be the temp file but it seems like after uploading to S3 the file is already closed for some reason Maybe there is something there as I have not seen this in the logs until now:

`/opt/python/xlsxwriter/workbook.py:338: UserWarning: Calling close() on already closed file.`

Comment: Logs from cloudwatch posted above after printing the objects type and the object, might help to narrow it down.

Comment: It's probably better to either use `upload_renewel_report` in the same scope where `tmp_file` is defined, or have `get_excel_file` create a regular file which the recipient is responsible for deleting.

Comment: Or have `get_excel_file` receive an open file handle as an argument, and let the caller worry about how that file gets created.

Comment: You're creating a somewhat strange situation because the temp file is being opened at least twice (because `s3_client.upload_file()` will need to open it in order to do the upload). I'm thinking perhaps it's possible that this second open is never closed — it's fairly common for software to be sloppy wrt closing all the files it opens, especially for reading them).

Answer (score 1):

NamedTemporaryFile can have some weirdness. I had a test that worked on linux but not windows with the exact behavior you describe. I fixed it by-

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False) as f:
    f.write(profile)
    f.seek(0)
    yield f.name
    f.close()
    os.unlink(f.name)
```

You also probably don't actually need to use the disk (if the file isn't too big for memory)

```
data = io.BinaryIO()
with pd.ExcelWriter(data) as writer:       
    df_report.to_excel(
        writer, sheet_name="Report", index=False, startrow=4
    )

s3_client.put_object(Body=data)
```

Comment: This looked to be really sound advice, so after running some `ls -al` and `df -h` in the container with smaller runs I could see hardly any of `/tmp` is taken up and for a large report the size is still only 60MB when generated locally.

The strangest thing is I have now gone with something similar to your example, I create the file using bytesIO and I STILL get the error telling me there is no space left on the device. Even after a redeployment of a lambda so it would be a fresh container.

It has to be something to do with how the pandas excel generation works as nothing else makes sense

Comment: Also for testing I increased the memory of the function to 8GB and it never gets anywhere near to using that before the file system error occurs.

Comment: looking at this code, I believe ExcelWriter is calling close when it leaves its context. As such, you want to do `data.seek(0)` and `s3_client.put_object` inside that block (I believe)